# . (dot) Regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++, delimiter

I would like to add  delimters to a .txt file.
Each line has the same amount of characters; and I know where the splits should happen.

For example,

MyNameIsHarry

I would like to transform the file to look like this instead:

My|Name|Is|Harry

I am on **notepad++ using Regular Expression**, and I can do this:
(..)(....)(..)(.....)

Replace with
\1|\2|\3|\4

Is there a more efficient way I can write this **regular expression**? Would i have to use 100 "." (dots) if there was a split of 100 characters?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Why can't you just replace ` +` with `|`?

Comment: @aroth because the line `MyNameIsHarry` does not contain any spaces. But perhaps `[A-Z]` can be used, if it's consistent that there should always be a space before a capital letter except for the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html at your service!

You can use `(.{100})` if you expect exactly 100.

as stated in the reference:

`{n} where n is an integer >= 1`
Repeats the previous item exactly n times.
Example: a{3} matches aaa

Answer (score 0):

If the text is all in the same format as your example you could just use:

```
   Find what : ([a-z])([A-Z]) 
Replace with : \1|\2
```

Make sure **Match case** and **Regular expression** are checked

**Replace All**